# Sending two variables in a single AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that gets the user from `$_POST`. It is something like this:

```
$login=$_POST['name'];
```

Then when I click a button it makes an AJAX request like the following:

```
      var id = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'Empresa=' + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processemp.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (html) {
```

This works fine but I need to send `$login` with the request too. How can I send two variables at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of the two solutions below, but please note that the script should be written in the PHP page, not in a separate javascript file.

The data option of [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) accepts two types of form: PlanObject or String.

> **data**
>   Type: PlainObject or String Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to
>   the url for GET-requests. See `processData` option to prevent this
>   automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an
>   Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the
>   value of the `traditional` setting (described below).

As a plain object,

```
 var id = $(this).val();
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processemp.php",
    data: {
        Empresa : id,
        login : '<?php echo $login; ?>'
    },
    success: function(html){
    }  
 });
```

As a query string,

```
 var id = $(this).val();
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processemp.php",
    data: 'Empresa=' + id + '&login= <?php echo $login; ?>',
    success: function(html){
    }  
 });
```

Comment: it seems my echoed var is always passing empty...Empresa pass ok but the login is empty, when i echo it in the processing ajax page...

Comment: @user2798634, `$login` derived from `$_POST['name']`. It is not concerned with `$.ajax` and out of question here.